# Why is css inline-block not working for a div inside another div?

Tags: html, css, display

I am trying to create a navigation menu. I have a div for the main navigation menu and another inside div for sub menus. below is the code

```
<body>
    <nav>
        <div class="navbutton">
            <a href="#">Home</a>
        </div>

        <div class="navbutton">
            <a href="#">Products</a>
            <div class="dropdownbox">
                <div class="navbutton">
                    <a href="#">None</a>
                </div>
                <div class="navbutton">
                    <a href="#">None</a>
                </div>
                <div class="navbutton">
                    <a href="#">None</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="navbutton">
            <a href="#">Contact</a>
        </div>
    </nav>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.navbutton {
    background-color: blanchedalmond;
    padding: 11px 25px;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

When I load the page, the outer div(main navigation menu) works fine but the inner divs (sub menu) are aligned vertical instead of horizontal despite .navbutton class being an inline-block. Why is this happening?

Comment: All your `.navbutton` are `100px` wide, even the one that holds the submenu. change to `min-width: 100px;` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because of "width: 100px;" so the sub menu items will take the full/same width of the parent. hence, it cannot aline horizontally